# Using Json.NET, how can I parse a list of objects with dynamic names into a List?

Tags: c#, json, web, json.net

Below is an example of the JSON format I'm receiving from an external API:

```
"object": {
  "property_1": {
    "values": {
      "value": 1,
      "displayValue": "1"
    }
  },
  "property_5": {
    "values": {
      "value": 3,
      "displayValue": "3"
    }
  },
  "property_8": {
    "values": {
      "value": 1,
      "displayValue": "1"
    }
  },
  "property_14": {
    "values": {
      "value": 392,
      "displayValue": "392.0"
    }
  },
  "property_17": {
    "values": {
      "value": 14,
      "displayValue": "14"
    }
  }
}
```

There are somewhere around 100 different property types that can be sent, but they all follow the same structure. The only distinction is the name of the property ("property_1", "property_5", etc). Rather than attempting to write a class with a long list of properties that are not always used, I think it'd be much more useful to parse this into a list of objects, using the property name in the resulting class like so:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PropertyValues Values { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyValues
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, the property name ("property_1", "property_5", etc) would be assigned to the Name field of the Property object.

How can this be accomplished using Json.NET?

Answer (score 9):

```
var result  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

You model is below

---

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, ValueWrapper> Object { get; set; }
}
public class ValueWrapper
{
    public PropertyValues Values { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyValues
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
}
```

BTW: Json.Net can handle *dynamic* more easily than proposed by @MatíasFidemraizer...

```
var val = ((dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring))
          .@object.property_14.values.value;

var val = ((dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring))
          .@object["property_14"].values.value;
```

But this approach would require you to know `property_14` will be returned by your server beforehand...

Comment: It's terrible to say some other contributor that has repeated your answer when a part of the whole answer is the exact approach provided by me. In other Q&As other answerers are more mature than you and usually use links to the other answerer saying "like has already said @matias-fidemraizer on his answer, you can use the dynamic approach too"... Actually, I care about contributing with good answers and suggestions that I really feel that are useful for the OP. In my case, I'm not a fame hunter, I just answer my point of view, I don't care if you get 100 more upvotes and I even get downvotes.

Comment: Well, I care if I get downvotes to IMPROVE my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the mention. IMHO and based on my experience, it's better to go with `ExpandoObject` than `JObject` on this cases, because remember that JSON.NET provide implicit conversions to turn a JSON value into a simple type like `string `, `bool`, `int`, and this can end up in some overload resolution issues... BTW, in other cases deserializing to `dynamic` as `JObject`  is enough...

Comment: Also now I understand your and @EZI concerns when you edited again and you show how you access `"property_14"`. I see that this issues are gone when you use `ExpandoObject`. Now the OP has 2 or 3 approaches to solve the same issue. Now I need to go to bed! Good night.

Answer (score 1):

There's even another approach: you can use [*expando objects*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>("JSON TEXT", new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

And you can access properties using dynamic typing:

```
long someValue = response.@object.property_1.values.value;
```

Also, since `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, you can use it like a dictionary and check if a property exists:

```
if(((IDictionary<string, object>)response.@object).ContainsKey("property_1"))
{

}
```

It seems like you're going to save a lot of time going this way!

### Answering hate on this answer

It seems like the most hate on my answer is focused on this @EZI comment:

> And suppose you don't know property_14 before deserializing the json..

And the other answerer @L.B argues this on his own answer:

> But this approach would require you to know property_14 will be
>   returned by your server beforehand...

In my case, I find that this concern is already addressed in my answer **when I mention that `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`. Perhaps you don't know that `property_14` will be part of deserialized object graph.** ***No problem***:

```
if(((IDictionary<string, object>)response.@object).ContainsKey("property_14"))
{
    // You've already addressed the issue, because you won't get a 
    // run-time exception since you'll access such property if it's already
    // in the returned response...
    object property_14 = response.@object.property_14;
}
```

Comment: So generic that, can be posted to any json related question.... And suppose you don't know `property_14` before deserializing the json....

Comment: It doesn't even work...  `string property14Value = response.property14Value;` throws exception....

Comment: @EZI Sorry but you know why it throws an exception, because it should be `response.object.property14value`. I'm going to fix this.

Comment: @EZI Fixed, BTW I feel that I got both a lot of love and hate (3 downvotes) while the approach works flawlessly in a lot of scenarios. And, IMHO, OP can take advantage of my approach. The fact that I gave a wrong dynamic property access is just a human error, while it doesn't defeat the purpose of my answer: I'm giving OP a good hint.

Comment: @EZI In the other hand, sure, it's a so generic answer but it strictly answers this concrete Q&A.

Comment: You are still unaware that `response.object.property14value` will also not work... Test your code before posting.... Post a concrete working code.... Otherwise It is just *"I know this and this, if you are interested take it"*

Comment: BTW: I'd also like to know  who voted +1 or -1 before/after testing the code in this answer....

Comment: @EZI Now the code works. I know that it's about providing quality answers, and this should include that the code actually works, but maybe the upvoters have found more value on the suggestion of using duck typing with expando objects instead of thinking if the code works or not. **Anyway, now the code is tested**.

Comment: @L.B But you can't argue I've copied your answer, because I've started with the dynamic approach from the scratch.

Comment: But I provided the nice and cleaner version. Even I think it is not the correct way to solve this question

Comment: @L.B Do you really think I need to repeat you? We both answered an hour ago, I was on the dynamic approach from the scratch.

Comment: @L.B Oh now I know that this went to a childish discussion. Ok, the point of contributing to StackOverflow is to share knowledge and good solutions. In my case, I've been publishing and editing my answer without touching yours, I didn't even know that you answered the same Q&A.... because I scrolled up when I edited my answer the last time.

Comment: **Saying wrong for an answer that is wrong is not "hate", just a comment. It is still wrong**

Comment: @EZI Fixed... but, again, the hate isn't justified. I guess you're saying it's wrong because of I didn't fix the thing about the `object` property when checking if a property existed casting the expando to dictionary...

Comment: @EZI If you've found any other issue, feel free to comment out what you found wrong so I can improve my answer. Downvoting or repeating "wrong wrong wrong" doesn't help too much. The worst part is that it's 0:40 here and I should be sleeping since more than an hour. Good night.